# Dropbox Datastore API: Reliably determining if the user is authenticated

Tags: java, android, authentication, dropbox, dropbox-api

### The Problem

I am using the [Dropbox Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore) to store information in my app. I am trying to figure out a reliable way to check if the user is authenticated with Dropbox.

Currently I am using this helper function:

```
public boolean isLoggedIn(Context context){
    LogHelper logHelper = new LogHelper();
    DbxAccount dropboxAcount = getDropboxAccountManager(context).getLinkedAccount();

    if(dropboxAcount == null){
        return false;
    } else{
        if(dropboxAcount.isLinked() && dropboxAcount.getAccountInfo() != null){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is if a user becomes unauthenticated after they have logged in, for example, if the user goes to their dropbox settings and unlinks the app. When this happens the above function will detect that the user is logged in, only when you try to perform an action that requires authentication(Like writing to a datastore) does the dropbox api realize that the user is not authenticated.

### The Question

Is there a reliable way to figure out if the user is authenticated with the Dropbox Datastore API?

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.addListener:

> `void addListener(AccountListener l)`
>
> Adds an `DbxAccountManager.AccountListener` which will be called
>   whenever a new account is linked or an existing account is unlinked.
>   The listener will be called regardless of whether the account was
>   unlinked using `DbxAccount.unlink()` or by the user on the Dropbox
>   website.

This notification will still presumably only fire after some communication with the server, since that's the only way for the client to know that something happened outside of the app.

Comment: So either I use listeners or I could attempt to interact with the server in some way which would update the logged in state, but using listeners seams like the proper way to do it.

Comment: @Noah Huppert You should definitely use the listener. It is easier to use and has direct support from the API.

Comment: @ColdConfusion the issue is, the listener does not fire an event if the user is already logged in.

Comment: @NoahHuppert Oh, okay. Well I guess you could try a combination of both the methods you mentioned.